# Creating and using array in Heap

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, heap-memory

as part of my study we are learning about using the "Heap" and were tasked with writing a short maths program with the use of pointers to reference and deference the heap.
As a bit of personal learning I've tried to replicate this with an Array, by creating one and using a Binary Search on it. But it simply won't work.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

//creating pointers
int* ii = new int;
int* top = new int;
int* bottom = new int;
int* uArray = new int[12];
int* uChoice = new int;

//assigning values in location of pointer
*ii = 5;
*top = 11;
*bottom = 0;

cout<<"Please input a value between 1 and 12 to find in the array: \t";
cin >> *uChoice;

for (int x = 0; x<12; x++) //adding values into the array
{
    uArray[x] = x;
    cout<<x;
    Sleep(1000);//checking loop works
}


while (uArray[*ii] != *uChoice)
{
    if (uArray[*ii] > *uChoice)
    {
        *bottom = *ii;
        *ii = (*top + *bottom)/2;
    }

    else 
    {
        *top = *ii;
        *ii = (*top + *bottom) /2;
    }

    if (*uChoice == *ii)
    {
        break;
    }


}

//clearing pointers.
delete ii;
delete top;
delete bottom;
delete uArray;
ii = 0;
top = 0;
bottom = 0;
uArray = 0;

cout<<uChoice<<" Found at position: \t"<< *ii;
Sleep(10000);
return 0;
```

}

Many thanks in advance.

[Edit:] The error occurs within the while loop. Something is happening that means its not correctly searching the array. Sorry i didn't clarify this.

Comment: Even if you are using pointers because you want to learn about them, use them properly. Having `ii`, `top`, `bottom` and `uChoice` be pointers is pointless, don’t do it. Also, be aware that in real code you wouldn’t use pointers at all in this situation, you’d use a container class.

Answer (score 3):

The delete keyword frees the memory pointed to by the pointer. So you should not try to use the pointer again after that.

Also, when the pointer is to an array you must use the delete[] uArray syntax, or the memory won't be freed properly.

Not sure if this is the part that "won't work" as you weren't more specific.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I was looking at the final cout of *ii after ii is deleted and reset to zero.

Comment: @IanGoldby Oh, true – I didn’t see that.

Comment: @WillzSawyer You’re lucky (or rather, unlucky!) that it works. It could equally well blow up or output a completely wrong result.

Comment: @KonradRudolph This wasn't the error, :( I put in 5 as my search number...well its the first number it looks at so i worked, the error is in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, Standard does not define "Heap" but as far implementations do it, `new` creates elements on **Freestore** and not Heap. `malloc()` creates elements on **Heap**.

**Good Read:**
[GotW #9: Memory Management - Part I](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/009.htm)

---

You have an **Undefined Behavior** lurking when you did:

```
   int* uArray = new int[12];
   delete uArray;
```

You need:

```
delete []uArray;
```

Comment: Freestore is a C++ concept whereas the heap is an OS concept. I'm wondering whether at the OS level, Freestore is on the heap anyway?

Comment: @IanGoldby: Yes it is.Given the usage specifications that Freestore demands, it has to be some sort of an Heap :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the while loop doesn't find the correct element in the array is nothing to do with the use of pointers. I could just give you the answer directly, but it will be more useful to you to find it yourself (before you look at the spoiler below).

I suggest you try running the code in a debugger. If you haven't used the debugger before, I strongly recommend you try it. Set a breakpoint at the start of the while loop. You might find it useful to write down on a piece of paper the contents of the uArray[] array for reference. Then step through the while loop one line at a time, paying careful attention to the if statement - whether it goes into the if clause or the else clause, and as a consequence whether it moves *top or *bottom. See if what happens makes sense given the value of *uChoice compared to uArray[*ii].

It's a trivial mistake and you'll kick yourself once you spot it. But the more useful lesson is in how to debug your code.

(If you don't have a debugger, you can achieve the same effect by inserting a few cout statements in the while loop to print out the values of the key variables.)

Here's the answer (mouse-over to see it):

> The greater-than operator should be a less-than in the test comparing uArray[*ii] and *uChoice. If the number you are searching for is less than the value in the array, you know it is in the bottom half, so you want to move the *top down*, not the bottom up.